# Подгружать страницу на весь экран при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку `Ajax` подгружал страницу на весь экран которая бы заменяла текущую, но на этой подгружаемой странице должна быть кнопка выхода, которая возвращает на тот адрес с которого была вызвана `ajax` функция.

`jQuery` очень приветствуется.

Я бы и сам это сделал, но я не пойму, как это описать в двух словах, что бы поискать в гугле.

Comment: на "тот адрес?" history.api хотим ? в чем проблема, скывайте старый контент, показывайте в новом блоке новый, в скрипте повесьте на body что-то типа

    $('body').('on','.backbutton',showprevcontent);

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример:

```
  $( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

Думаю, что надо будет еще передать линк странички, с которой был редирект такой себе для того, чтобы можно было так же вернуться динамически назад.